# bootstrap modal dialog box not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal dialog box that is supposed to show up, the code is as follows:

```
        <span style="vertical-align:top;"><a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-small btn-red" data-toggle="modal"> Delete League </a></span>

<!-- start of modal dialog box -->
<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
    <p>Ut nunc libero, sodales venenatis gravida nec, posuere quis ante.
      Phasellus lobortis molestie felis, vitae sagittis ipsum vehicula lobortis.
      </p>
    <p>Quisque lacus mi, gravida vel facilisis ac, malesuada vel augue.
      In ac leo eget tellus aliquet aliquam. Nam faucibus urna ac justo fringilla eu
      sollicitudin quam pretium. Proin pellentesque adipiscing sapien, non dignissim
      massa porttitor dictum. Integer tempor aliquam arcu, eget vehicula ipsum auctor at.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer" data-dismiss="modal">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-green">Save changes</a>
  </div>
</div>
<%-- end of modal dialog box --%>
```

the code simple does nothing, nothing happens when clicked, looked at many examples on the net and they all appear the same. I have a packages.config file and this appears to include the link to bootstrap. All the rest of the site regards bootstrap I would say is working fine, so I believe the link is there. The package file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="2.1.3" targetFramework="net35" />
</packages>
```

I'm guessing I must be missing a link to something somewhere, unless the error is with my code, any one any suggestions...

Comment: you should try `$('#myModal').modal('toggle');` in the document.ready event or whenever u want the modal to show up. also can you check your console to see if you have any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Your modal is working but you need to remove 'hide' class from the outer div. Also in order to have the right visual aspect you need to add two more wrapper divs immediately after the outer one having classes 'modal-dialog' and respectively 'modal-content'. Please find below the adapted code:

```
<!-- start of modal dialog box -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3>Modal header</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
                <p>
                    Ut nunc libero, sodales venenatis gravida nec, posuere quis ante.
                    Phasellus lobortis molestie felis, vitae sagittis ipsum vehicula lobortis.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Quisque lacus mi, gravida vel facilisis ac, malesuada vel augue.
                    In ac leo eget tellus aliquet aliquam. Nam faucibus urna ac justo fringilla eu
                    sollicitudin quam pretium. Proin pellentesque adipiscing sapien, non dignissim
                    massa porttitor dictum. Integer tempor aliquam arcu, eget vehicula ipsum auctor at.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" data-dismiss="modal">
                <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-green">Save changes</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end of modal dialog box -->
```

In order to display the modal you can use:

```
$('#myModal').modal();
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

Please check the this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/marianc/snn6347r/) for a working demo.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, I think I was missing the link to the JavaScript file, when I added the following it appeared to work: <script src="../../javascripts/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>